# Parsing of a string with the length specified within the string

Tags: regex, backreference

Example data:

> 029Extract this specific string. Do not capture anything else.

In the example above, I would like to capture the first n characters immediately after the 3 digit entry which defines the value of n. I.E. the 29 characters "Extract this specific string."

I can do this within a loop, but it is slow. I would like (if it is possible) to achieve this with a single regex statement instead, using some kind of backreference. Something like:

```
(\d{3})(.{\1})
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: I can be flexible, I have used PHP, Javascript and a couple others to work on the same data.

Comment: You won't be able to have the "29" be interpreted as the number of characters for the regex to read using the regex alone. You will need to extract the 29 first, then build your expression. I don't think a regex is really warranted here anyway.

Comment: Essentially that is what I want to know, if this is achievable within a regex. If it is not possible to parse "029" as a number, that is one answer.

Comment: Think about it like this:  Certainly the `\d{3}` knows that it's dealing with numeric digits (or rather numeric characters); how does the `\1` know that what it captured was numeric? In a very general sense, what would/could the regex engine do if it encountered `([a-z]{3}(.{\1})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With perl, you can do:

```
my $str = '029Extract this specific string. Do not capture anything else.';
$str =~ s/^(\d+)(.*)$/substr($2,0,$1)/e;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
Extract this specific string.
```

Comment: A clever one line solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a regex?

From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info:

> Fools Rush in Where Angels Fear to Tread
>
> The tremendous power and expressivity of modern regular expressions
>   can seduce the gullible — or the foolhardy — into trying to use
>   regular expressions on every string-related task they come across.
>   This is a bad idea in general, ...

Here's a **Python** three-liner:

```
foo = "029Extract this specific string. Do not capture anything else."
substr_len = int(foo[:3])
print foo[3:substr_len+3]
```

And here's a **PHP** three-liner:

```
$foo = "029Extract this specific string. Do not capture anything else.";
$substr_len = (int) substr($foo,0,3);
echo substr($foo,3,substr_len+3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with single regex, while you can use knowledge where regex stop processing to use substr. For example in JavaScript you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/75Tm5/

```
var input = "blahblah 011I want this, and 029Extract this specific string. Do not capture anything else.";
var regex = /(\d{3})/g;
var matches;
while ((matches = regex.exec(input)) != null) {
    alert(input.substr(regex.lastIndex, matches[0]));
}
```

This will returns both lines:

```
I want this
Extract this specific string.
```

Depending on what you really want, you can modify Regex to match only numbers starting from line beginning, match only first match etc